# Can I use the same jQuery statement with different selectors on the same page?

Tags: jquery, css, svg

This may seem trivial, but I have run into a slight problem. I have SVG icons on my page, that when hovered over, should change state to show a hidden div. I got the first icon to do this, but subsequent icons are not working. I have narrowed the problem down to the jQuery, due to the fact that the css (cursor: pointer;) still works for each icon, but the hidden div supposed to show does not. My question is this, can I have multiple jQuery statements like this

```
$(".div-g").hover(
   function() {
     $(this).find(".div-hidden").css("display","block");
   },
   function() {
     $(this).find(".div-hidden").css("display","none");
   }
);
```

for each of my SVG's. So for example, I would use the same statement, but just replace "div" with "div1" and so on. I don't see why not, but I'm not sure why it isn't as simple as it was with the first icon. For clarity, each of my SVG's have classes that look like this

```
<rect style="display:none;" class="div-hidden div-hidden-rect" width="34.02" height="34.02"/>
<text style="display:none;" class="div-hidden" x="8" y="10">
```

and css that looks like this

```
.div-g:hover {
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
}
.div-hidden {
text-anchor: middle;
text-align: center;
font-size: .5rem;
display: inline-block;
position: center;
}
.div-hidden-rect {
fill: $whiteblue;
opacity: .96;
}
```

where .div-g represents the SVG . So, is my issue using the same jQuery statement with different selectors, or something I am not seeing?

Comment: *"Can I use the same jQuery statement with different selectors on the same page?"* The short answer is yes. But since you haven't shown any example of what your "div1" elements might look like, it's hard to show you a specific example.

Comment: You're basically asking if you can have more than one line of code on the same page.  Yes, you can.  But it's not really clear what the problem is that you're trying to describe.  I suspect you've made a mistake in your diagnosis and you're asking us about the mistake instead of about the root of the problem.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear on that. My "div1" (which is just the prefix that I would change for each, so div1-g, div1-hidden, div1-hiddenr-rect) is a rectangle, the same size as the SVG image.

Comment: On hover, I am trying to change my SVG image to a simple rectangle. I got it to work with one of my SVG icons, but I have many more that will not change.

Comment: @hoolakoola: Can you provide a minimal and complete example of the problem to demonstrate?  It seems pretty unnecessary to have to write the same code many times when every element is supposed to do the same thing.

Comment: But it's not exactly the same, each rectangle will be a different color, otherwise I would just use a shared class.

Comment: @hoolakoola provide your html please. I am sure your html contains elements with same id/classes resulting in issur

Comment: Better yet, make a jsFiddle or add a snippet here showing the behaviour

Comment: @DelightedD0D well, I attempted to make a fiddle, and I get the same issue I am experiencing on my localhost. https://jsfiddle.net/dgoetzit/a5b0dj1f/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.div-g, .div1').hover(
  function(){
    $('.div-hidden').css({display: 'block'});
  }, function(){
    $('.div-hidden').css({display: 'none'});
  });
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Your class selector will match any number of divs with a matching class, for instance:

```
<div id="div-1" class="svg-container">
  <rect style="display:none;" class="div-hidden div-hidden-rect" width="34.02" height="34.02"/>
  <text style="display:none;" class="div-hidden" x="8" y="10">
</div>

<div id="div-2" class="svg-container">
  <rect style="display:none;" class="div-hidden div-hidden-rect" width="34.02" height="34.02"/>
  <text style="display:none;" class="div-hidden" x="8" y="10">
</div>

<div id="div-3" class="svg-container">
  <rect style="display:none;" class="div-hidden div-hidden-rect" width="34.02" height="34.02"/>
  <text style="display:none;" class="div-hidden" x="8" y="10">
</div>
```

Selecting all divs with class .svg-container should work just fine.

```
$(".svg-container").hover(
   function() {
     $(this).find(".div-hidden").css("display","block");
   },
   function() {
     $(this).find(".div-hidden").css("display","none");
   }
);
```

Styling them individually is simple as well. You're using a variable in your css so I'm assuming it's LESS/SASS?

```
.svg-container {

    &:hover {
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .div-hidden {
        text-anchor: middle;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: .5rem;
        display: inline-block;
        position: center;
    }

    .div-hidden-rect {
        opacity: .96;
    }
}


#div-1 {
    .div-hidden-rect {
        fill: $whiteblue;
    }
}

#div-2 {
    .div-hidden-rect {
        fill: $somethingelse;
    }
}

#div-3 {
    .div-hidden-rect {
        fill: $somethingelseagain;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would suffice but each rectangle for each SVG will be different color, so I have to use a unique class for each one.

Comment: I've added an example of this, you can add as many classes as you want to your containers and target them individually or collectively. If you're only ever going to use them once I'd recommend using ID's for your unique identifiers as you'll get better performance.

Comment: If each rect has its own color, consider just sticking the colors themselves in a `data-*` attribute and using that attribute (e.g. `$(el).data('color')`) instead of class name, much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, all you really need is `$(this).find(".an-hidden").toggle();`

```js
$(".hover-change").hover(function() {
     $(this).find(".an-hidden").toggle();
});
```

```css
.an-1 {
        fill: #2ea3e4;
      }
.an-g:hover {
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.an-hidden {
 text-anchor: middle;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: .5rem;
 display: inline-block;
 position: center;
}
.an-hidden-rect {
 fill: #F8FDF7;
 opacity: .96;

}
.an-hidden-text {
 fill: #2ea3e4;
}
.an-hidden-smtext {
 margin-top: 1rem;
 font-size: .15rem;
 fill: #2ea3e4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="test_icon" data-name="Test Icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 34.02 34.02">
  <defs>
    
  </defs>
  <title>analysis_icon</title>
  <g class="an-g hover-change">
    <rect class="an-1" width="14.02" height="14.02"/>
    <rect style="display:none;" class="an-hidden an-hidden-rect" width="14.02" height="14.02"/>
    <text style="display:none;" class="an-hidden" x="8" y="10">
      <tspan x="50%" y="35%" dy=".1em" class="an-hidden-text">Text Title</tspan>
      <tspan x="50%" dy="1.9em" class="an-hidden-smtext">text</tspan>
      <tspan x="50%" dy="1.9em" class="an-hidden-smtext">more text</tspan>
      <tspan x="50%" dy="1.9em" class="an-hidden-smtext">more more text</tspan>
      </text>-->

  </g>
</svg>
<svg id="test_icon2" data-name="Test Icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 34.02 34.02">
  <defs>
    
  </defs>
  <title>analysis_icon</title>
  <g class="an-b hover-change">
    <rect class="an-1" width="14.02" height="14.02"/>
    <rect style="display:none;" class="an-hidden an-hidden-rect" width="14.02" height="14.02"/>
    <text style="display:none;" class="an-hidden" x="8" y="10">
      <tspan x="50%" y="35%" dy=".1em" class="an-hidden-text">Text Title</tspan>
      <tspan x="50%" dy="1.9em" class="an-hidden-smtext">text</tspan>
      <tspan x="50%" dy="1.9em" class="an-hidden-smtext">more text</tspan>
      <tspan x="50%" dy="1.9em" class="an-hidden-smtext">more more text</tspan>
      </text>-->

  </g>
</svg>
<svg id="test_icon3" data-name="Test Icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 34.02 34.02">
  <defs>
    
  </defs>
  <title>analysis_icon</title>
  <g class="an-d  hover-change">
    <rect class="an-1" width="14.02" height="14.02"/>
    <rect style="display:none;" class="an-hidden an-hidden-rect" width="14.02" height="14.02"/>
    <text style="display:none;" class="an-hidden" x="8" y="10">
      <tspan x="50%" y="35%" dy=".1em" class="an-hidden-text">Text Title</tspan>
      <tspan x="50%" dy="1.9em" class="an-hidden-smtext">text</tspan>
      <tspan x="50%" dy="1.9em" class="an-hidden-smtext">more text</tspan>
      <tspan x="50%" dy="1.9em" class="an-hidden-smtext">more more text</tspan>
      </text>-->

  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes basically. The confusion arose because I have 8 icons, and the first one I tried worked, but every subsequent one does not. I will try this with all of them and see if this solves my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @hoolakoola I added 2 more icons to the demo just to be sure, but yeah, this method doesnt really care how many you have, should just work :)

Comment: I am so confused haha. It works for the first still, but none of the rest :(

Comment: Mind you my SVG's are all different and have different classes specific to each one.

Comment: Are you certain that all of your elements have the `an-g` class?

Comment: I am certain they don't. I have an "an-g" class, a "pl-g" class, and so on. But every other selector in the SVG shares that prefix.

Comment: That is why this is so frustrating, all I'm doing is changing the selector prefix, leaving everything else the same from icon to icon.

Comment: Ah, ok. Youll need a way to select them all. If you control the html, the easiest way would be to add a secondary class to them all like `hover-change` see the updated example

Comment: But again, I change every class prefix in a particular SVG, so in <g> "an-b", every class gets that prefix "an-b-hidden an-b-hidden-rect"

Comment: Honestly,  I would suggest that you give them all a class of `an` (or something more descriptive). Use the `an` class to select all of the element  and to apply common css like maybe `height` and `width` and then have a secondary class like `b` that adds the styling that is specific to that element, like background color.  Then, dont use `.an-b-hidden-rect` use `.an.b .hidden-rect`

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I finally figured it out, and it was as silly as I thought it would be. In my script, I simply changed the order of the jQuery statements, putting the statement for the first box last, and it solved it.

Comment: @hoolakoola Im glad you got it sorted.

Comment: I know this is out of the scope of the original question, but is there a process of operations that I perhaps messed up? Or what else would cause this?